# Centrar una búsqueda dentro de una página en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo este código que lleva a una sección dentro del site. Todo está perfecto, pero mi problema es que al llevarme a la sección me deja la información en la parte superior de la pantalla y me gustaría que dejara la información en el centro de la pantalla. No tengo ni idea de cómo hacer eso y ya he buscado por todos lados.

```
<nav>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="#primeira"> Top 1 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#segunda"> Top 2 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#terceira"> Top 3 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#quarta"> Top 4 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#quinta"> Top 5 </a></li>>
          </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
nav{
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: serif;
}
nav ul{
    height: auto;
    margin:0px;
}
nav li{
      display: inline;
}

nav a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hay que indicar posición relativa y adaptar el margen y la distancia hasta la parte superior, creo que con esto te irá perfecto y te quedará en el centro de la pantalla:

```
nav{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: serif;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que quieres es centrar el contenido del nav, en ese caso tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
nav{
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: serif;
}

nav ul{
    display:flex; /*Accedes a las propiedades flex*/
    justify-content:center; /*Alineas de forma horizontal*/
    align-items:center; /*Alineas de forma vertical*/
}
```

Comment: Si no es esto lo que querías hacer por favor comentame aquí o reformula la pregunta, gracias